# vba excel macro not case sensitive

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code and I need some help in makeing it not case sensitive. Right now the serch is case sensitive and I have some excel tables that contains data that are both in uppercase and inlowercase.
 Thanks

```
Sub FormatSelection()

    Dim cl As Range
    Dim SearchText As String
    Dim StartPos As Integer
    Dim EndPos As Integer
    Dim TestPos As Integer
    Dim TotalLen As Integer

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    SearchText = Application.InputBox _
    (Prompt:="Enter string.", Title:="Which string to format?", Type:=2)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    If SearchText = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        For Each cl In Selection
          TotalLen = Len(SearchText)
          StartPos = InStr(cl, SearchText)
          TestPos = 0
          Do While StartPos > TestPos
            With cl.Characters(StartPos, TotalLen).Font
              .FontStyle = "Bold"
              .ColorIndex = 3
            End With
            EndPos = StartPos + TotalLen
            TestPos = TestPos + EndPos
            StartPos = InStr(TestPos, cl, SearchText, vbTextCompare)
          Loop
        Next cl
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you not just use `Option Compare Text`?  Alternatively, add `vbTextCompare` arg to your first `InStr`.

Comment: Of the two that @blackworx notes, the latter would be preferable for sake of good habit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this one line

StartPos = InStr(Ucase(cl), Ucase(SearchText))

Comment: Ucase will change both sides of the comparison to upper case

Comment: Thank you verry much. It works perfect. Thank you again.